# How does one programmatically discover a blog feed on a given domain?

Tags: php, xml, rss, blogs

I have a list of 10,000 company websites and am trying to discover their blog feeds if they have one (any and all rss versions).  I don't want to crawl them if i don't have to, so are there any tools, or specific tricks that would find a large percentage of their feeds if one exists?

My first thought was to look for the standard location of a blog feed, but most of these sites aren't primarily blogs, they are corporate sites.  Any suggestions are welcome.

PHP based tools are preferred.

Comment: Do you know if there is any particular blog software being used?

Comment: i have no other information about these urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crawling them is the only sensible option, you probably only need to hit their homepages. I'd make use of [Feed::Find](http://beta.metacpan.org/module/Feed%3a%3aFind) to fetch the pages and detect the feed URIs.

Comment: do you know of anything similar to feed::find that is written in php?

Comment: No, but it isn't exactly a complicated problem, you could port the [source](http://api.metacpan.org/source/BTROTT/Feed-Find-0.07/lib/Feed/Find.pm). (Although I wouldn't bother, since it shouldn't be hard to learn enough Perl to read a list of URIs, loop over it, feed it into the example in the Feed::Find docs, and then store the results)

Answer (score 2):

When you just paste a blog URL to google reader, it can automatically save RSS path. Most probably what Google Reader does is inspecting the source code for things like

`<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" ..` or

`<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss" ..`

That's how Firefox and some other browsers can show a RSS icon when you are surfing on a regular page. You can see Firefox source code for a healthy result.

In addition to those, you may consider looking at `/blog`, `/rss`, `/blog/feed`, `blog.*.com/feed`, `/atom` or URLs like `*.xml`, `*.feed`, `*.rss` Those are almost most popular RSS paths imho.